# awk replace empty fields/columns with added string and aligning them

Tags: string, sorting, awk, replace, multiple-columns

hello i am struggling with this for serveral hours of trying to find some solution here from start to replace just empty field for columns with eg. NA string

tried following initially without moving further to have some expected output

```
awk -v OFS=' ' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/^[[:space:]]+$/,"",$i); $i=($i==""?NA:$i)}; print}' file  >> not worked
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/*$/)$i=NA}1' file | column -t                                            >> not worked
awk 'NF==23{$0=$0"NA"}1' file
awk  'BEGIN{OFS=" "}{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if($i==""){$i=l}else{l=$i}}print}' file
awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /^ *$/) $i = 0 }; 1' file
```

this is input:

```
5 STAT in DOCK 3 BAY1 SHIP OK SHA OK SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
5 STAT in DOCK 3 BAY2 SHIP OK SHA OK SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
5 STAT in DOCK 5 CONT CARG OK SHI OK SHJ
5 STAT in DOCK 5 CONG CARG OK SHF OK SHG
11 STAT in DOCK 8 BAY7 SHIP BAD SHA OK SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
11 STAT in DOCK 8 BAY9 SHIP OK SHA OK SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
7 STAT in DOCK 7 CONT7 SHIP BAD SHA OK SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
191 STAT in DOCK 20 FRI5 CARG OK SHA BAD SHB BAD SHF BAD SHG 
1 STAT in DOCK 50 BAY4 CARGB BAD SHF OK SHG
```

this is goal 
//expected output 1

```
5   STAT in DOCK 3  BAY1  SHIP  OK  SHA OK  SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
5   STAT in DOCK 3  BAY2  SHIP  OK  SHA OK  SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
5   STAT in DOCK 5  CONT  CARG  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  OK  SHI OK  SHJ
5   STAT in DOCK 5  CONG  CARG  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  OK  SHF OK  SHG NA  NA  NA  NA
11  STAT in DOCK 8  BAY7  SHIP  BAD SHA OK  SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
11  STAT in DOCK 8  BAY9  SHIP  OK  SHA OK  SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
7   STAT in DOCK 7  CONT7 SHIP  BAD SHA OK  SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
191 STAT in DOCK 20 FRI5  CARG  OK  SHA BAD SHB NA  NA  NA  NA  BAD SHF BAD SHG NA  NA  NA  NA
1   STAT in DOCK 50 BAY4  CARGB NA  NA  NA  NA  BAD NA  NA  NA  BAD SHF OK  SHG NA  NA  NA  NA
```

-- removed expected output nr2 as its confusing

Comment: Where does that `BAD` in group `GRB` at last line come from?

Comment: If it's a typo, then this should work: `awk 'BEGIN{a[0]="SHA";a[1]="SHC";a[2]="SHF";a[3]="SHI"}NF<23{f=9;for(f=9,i=0;i<4;++i){if($f!=a[i]){$(f-1)="NA NA NA NA "$(f-1);$0=$0}f+=4}}1' file`

Comment: hello @oguzismail  BAD is opposite of OK in given column, and its resulted from system, where for example GRB is just group consisted of SHC and SHD and for example its BAD or OK value for SHC or even for SHD , those groups are not mandatory its just only IDEA how to group them for better overview like in expected format nr.2

Comment: I got it, I'm asking where did that "BAD" at row 9 column 12 in your expected output come from?

Comment: @oguzismail aah its typo

Comment: okay i partly solve it like this

`code 
awk -v OFS=" " 'NR==1 {cols=NF} {$1=$1; for (i=NF+1; i <= cols; i++) $i = "NA"} 1' file  code`  but still need to do that ordering

Comment: The one I posted above works fine here

Comment: @ya801 if there's a typo in your question then fix it - don't just add a comment saying "its a typo"!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v OFS=" " 'NR==1 {cols=NF} {$1=$1; for (i=NF+1; i <= cols; i++) $i = "NA"} 1' file
```

well this one works only in generic way if there is added header with the same expected amount columns to be used (without supplied "dummy" header simply it will not work), still playing with both versions yet

```
e.g.
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
5 STAT in DOCK 5 CONT CARG OK SHI OK SHJ
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    numFlds = split("SHA SHB SHC SHD SHF SHG SHI SHJ",fldList)
    for (i in fldList) {
        fldName = fldList[i]
        fldSet[fldName]
    }
}
{
    for (i=1; (i<=NF) && !($(i+1) in fldSet); i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $i, OFS
    }

    delete fldVals
    for (; i<=NF; i+=2) {
        fldName = $(i+1)
        fldVals[fldName] = $i
    }

    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++) {
        fldName = fldList[fldNr]
        if (fldName in fldVals) {
            fldVal = fldVals[fldName]
        }
        else {
            fldName = fldVal = "NA"
        }
        printf "%s%s%s%s", fldVal, OFS, fldName, (fldNr<numFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t -o' '
5   STAT in DOCK 3  BAY1  SHIP  OK  SHA OK  SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
5   STAT in DOCK 3  BAY2  SHIP  OK  SHA OK  SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
5   STAT in DOCK 5  CONT  CARG  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  OK  SHI OK  SHJ
5   STAT in DOCK 5  CONG  CARG  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  OK  SHF OK  SHG NA  NA  NA  NA
11  STAT in DOCK 8  BAY7  SHIP  BAD SHA OK  SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
11  STAT in DOCK 8  BAY9  SHIP  OK  SHA OK  SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
7   STAT in DOCK 7  CONT7 SHIP  BAD SHA OK  SHB BAD SHC BAD SHD BAD SHF BAD SHG BAD SHI BAD SHJ
191 STAT in DOCK 20 FRI5  CARG  OK  SHA BAD SHB NA  NA  NA  NA  BAD SHF BAD SHG NA  NA  NA  NA
1   STAT in DOCK 50 BAY4  CARGB NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  BAD SHF OK  SHG NA  NA  NA  NA
```